# pandas: combine two columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that has multiple columns in it:

```
Index: 239897 entries, 2012-05-11 15:20:00 to 2012-06-02 23:44:51
Data columns:
foo                   11516  non-null values
bar                   228381  non-null values
Time_UTC              239897  non-null values
dtstamp               239897  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4), object(1)
```

where `foo` and `bar` are columns which contain the same data yet are named differently. Is there are a way to move the rows which make up `foo` into `bar`, ideally whilst maintaining the name of `bar`?

In the end the DataFrame should appear as:

```
Index: 239897 entries, 2012-05-11 15:20:00 to 2012-06-02 23:44:51
Data columns:
bar                   239897  non-null values
Time_UTC              239897  non-null values
dtstamp               239897  non-null values
dtypes: float64(4), object(1)
```

That is the NaN values that made up bar were replaced by the values from `foo`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
pandas.concat([df['foo'].dropna(), df['bar'].dropna()]).reindex_like(df)
```

If you want that data to become the new column `bar`, just assign the result to `df['bar']`.

Comment: I am not seeing `concat` as a function in the pandas namespace; I'm not sure what I am missing.

Comment: What version of pandas do you have?  The function is documented here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects

Comment: I was running pandas ver 0.6.1 which doesn't have the concat function included. An upgrade to v 0.7.3 brings concat into the namespace. Works like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

you can use directly fillna and assigning the result to the column 'bar'

```
df['bar'].fillna(df['foo'], inplace=True)
del df['foo']
```

general example:

```
import pandas as pd
#creating the table with two missing values
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]}, index = [1,2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[5,6]}, index = [3,4])
dftot = pd.concat((df1, df2))
print dftot
#creating the dataframe to fill the missing values
filldf = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,7,7,7]})

#filling 
print dftot.fillna(filldf)
```

Comment: but do note that since filldf is indexed 0..3 while dftot is indexed 1..4,  dftot.fillna(filldf)['a'][4] will be nan. not 7.0

Answer (score 6):

More modern pandas versions (since at least 0.12) have the [`combine_first()` and `update()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#merging-together-values-within-series-or-dataframe-columns) methods for DataFrame and Series objects. For example if your DataFrame were called `df`, you would do:

```
df.bar.combine_first(df.foo)
```

which would only alter Nan values of the `bar` column to match the `foo` column, and would do so inplace. To overwrite non-Nan values in `bar` with those in `foo`, you would use the `update()` method.

Answer (score 5):

Another option, use the `.apply()` method on the frame.  You can do reassign a column with deference to existing data...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# get your data into a dataframe

# replace content in "bar" with "foo" if "bar" is null
df["bar"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["foo"] if row["bar"] == np.NaN else row["bar"], axis=1) 

# note: change 'np.NaN' with null values you have like an empty string
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch @Veenit

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `numpy` too.

`df['bar'] = np.where(pd.isnull(df['bar']),df['foo'],df['bar'])`