# String concatenation of two pandas columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a following `DataFrame`:

```
from pandas import *
df = DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3]})
```

It looks like this:

```
    bar foo
0    1   a
1    2   b
2    3   c
```

Now I want to have something like:

```
     bar
0    1 is a
1    2 is b
2    3 is c
```

How can I achieve this?
I tried the following:

```
df['foo'] = '%s is %s' % (df['bar'], df['foo'])
```

but it gives me a wrong result:

```
>>>print df.ix[0]

bar                                                    a
foo    0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: bar is 0    1
1    2
2
Name: 0
```

Sorry for a dumb question, but this one [pandas: combine two columns in a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972410/pandas-combine-two-columns-in-a-dataframe) wasn't helpful for me.

Answer (score 173):

```
df['bar'] = df.bar.map(str) + " is " + df.foo
```

Answer (score 165):

This question has already been answered, but I believe it would be good to throw some useful methods not previously discussed into the mix, and compare all methods proposed thus far in terms of performance.

Here are some useful solutions to this problem, in increasing order of performance.

---

#### **[`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)**

This is a simple [`str.format`](https://pyformat.info)-based approach.

```
df['baz'] = df.agg('{0[bar]} is {0[foo]}'.format, axis=1)
df
  foo  bar     baz
0   a    1  1 is a
1   b    2  2 is b
2   c    3  3 is c
```

You can also use f-string formatting here:

```
df['baz'] = df.agg(lambda x: f"{x['bar']} is {x['foo']}", axis=1)
df
  foo  bar     baz
0   a    1  1 is a
1   b    2  2 is b
2   c    3  3 is c
```

---

#### **[`char.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.chararray.html)-based Concatenation**

Convert the columns to concatenate as `chararrays`, then add them together.

```
a = np.char.array(df['bar'].values)
b = np.char.array(df['foo'].values)

df['baz'] = (a + b' is ' + b).astype(str)
df
  foo  bar     baz
0   a    1  1 is a
1   b    2  2 is b
2   c    3  3 is c
```

---

#### **[List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)**

I cannot overstate how underrated list comprehensions are in pandas.

```
df['baz'] = [str(x) + ' is ' + y for x, y in zip(df['bar'], df['foo'])]
```

Alternatively, using `str.join` to concat (will also scale better):

```
df['baz'] = [
    ' '.join([str(x), 'is', y]) for x, y in zip(df['bar'], df['foo'])]
```

```
df
  foo  bar     baz
0   a    1  1 is a
1   b    2  2 is b
2   c    3  3 is c
```

List comprehensions excel in string manipulation, because string operations are inherently hard to vectorize, and most pandas "vectorised" functions are basically wrappers around loops. I have written extensively about this topic in [For loops with pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care). In general, if you don't have to worry about index alignment, use a list comprehension when dealing with string and regex operations.

The list comp above by default does not handle NaNs. However, you could always write a function wrapping a try-except if you needed to handle it.

```
def try_concat(x, y):
    try:
        return str(x) + ' is ' + y
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return np.nan


df['baz'] = [try_concat(x, y) for x, y in zip(df['bar'], df['foo'])]
```

---

#### **`perfplot` Performance Measurements**

[image]

Graph generated using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot). Here's the [complete code listing](https://gist.github.com/Coldsp33d/f261adea57c70be1ba16caba15daffe4).

**Functions**

> ```
> def brenbarn(df):
>     return df.assign(baz=df.bar.map(str) + " is " + df.foo)
>
> def danielvelkov(df):
>     return df.assign(baz=df.apply(
>         lambda x:'%s is %s' % (x['bar'],x['foo']),axis=1))
>
> def chrimuelle(df):
>     return df.assign(
>         baz=df['bar'].astype(str).str.cat(df['foo'].values, sep=' is '))
>
> def vladimiryashin(df):
>     return df.assign(baz=df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ' is '.join(x), axis=1))
>
> def erickfis(df):
>     return df.assign(
>         baz=df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['bar']} is {x['foo']}", axis=1))
>
> def cs1_format(df):
>     return df.assign(baz=df.agg('{0[bar]} is {0[foo]}'.format, axis=1))
>
> def cs1_fstrings(df):
>     return df.assign(baz=df.agg(lambda x: f"{x['bar']} is {x['foo']}", axis=1))
>
> def cs2(df):
>     a = np.char.array(df['bar'].values)
>     b = np.char.array(df['foo'].values)
>
>     return df.assign(baz=(a + b' is ' + b).astype(str))
>
> def cs3(df):
>     return df.assign(
>         baz=[str(x) + ' is ' + y for x, y in zip(df['bar'], df['foo'])])
> ```

Comment: That's all I always wanted to know about string concatenation in pandas, but was too afraid too ask!

Comment: Can you please update the plot to next level 10**4 (or even higher), a quick visual answer with the current plot limited to 10**3 (1000 which is very small for today condition) is that cs3 is the best, eventually when you see brenbarn is looking less exponential than cs3, so most probably for large dataset brenbarn is the best (faster) answer.

Comment: @VelizarVESSELINOV Updated! What surprises me is that the numpy concatenation is slower than both the list comp and the pandas concatenation.

Comment: Have you considered using `df['bar'].tolist()` and `df['foo'].tolist()` in `cs3()`? My guess is that it would increase "base" time slightly but it would scale better.

Comment: Great ! I've encountered a problem in my case with 10^11 rows. Proposed solutions did not work. I proposed another one, closer to factor multiplication in R software, here using categories. Could be an idea to test it also in your case. Regards

Comment: Please include the fastest way: `df.bar.astype(str) + ' is ' + df.foo`

Answer (score 46):

The problem in your code is that you want to apply the operation on every row. The way you've written it though takes the whole 'bar' and 'foo' columns, converts them to strings and gives you back one big string. You can write it like:

```
df.apply(lambda x:'%s is %s' % (x['bar'],x['foo']),axis=1)
```

It's longer than the other answer but is more generic (can be used with values that are not strings).

Answer (score 16):

You could also use

```
df['bar'] = df['bar'].str.cat(df['foo'].values.astype(str), sep=' is ')
```

Comment: This doesn't work since df['bar'] is not a string column. The correct assignment is `df['bar'] = df['bar'].astype(str).str.cat(df['foo'], sep=' is ')`.

Answer (score 13):

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: ' is '.join(x), axis=1)

0    1 is a
1    2 is b
2    3 is c
dtype: object
```

Comment: This answer also works with undetermined number of columns (> 1) & undetermined column names, making it more useful than the rest.

Answer (score 9):

`series.str.cat` is the most flexible way to approach this problem:

For  `df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3]})`

```
df.foo.str.cat(df.bar.astype(str), sep=' is ')

>>>  0    a is 1
     1    b is 2
     2    c is 3
     Name: foo, dtype: object
```

OR

```
df.bar.astype(str).str.cat(df.foo, sep=' is ')

>>>  0    1 is a
     1    2 is b
     2    3 is c
     Name: bar, dtype: object
```

Unlike `.join()` (which is for joining list contained in a single Series), this method is for joining 2 Series together. It also allows you to ignore or replace `NaN` values as desired.

Comment: Can you demonstrate ignoring/replacing `NaN` values with `str.cat`?

Answer (score 7):

It's been 10 years and no one proposed the most simple and intuitive way which is 50% faster than all examples proposed on these 10 years.

```
df.bar.astype(str) + ' is ' + df.foo
```

Comment: It's clearly now the right answer while using `astype(str)`.

Answer (score 4):

@DanielVelkov answer is the proper one BUT
using string literals is faster:

```
# Daniel's
%timeit df.apply(lambda x:'%s is %s' % (x['bar'],x['foo']),axis=1)
## 963 µs ± 157 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# String literals - python 3
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: f"{x['bar']} is {x['foo']}", axis=1)
## 849 µs ± 4.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most concise solution for arbitrary numbers of columns is a short-form version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43694761/1397061):

`df.astype(str).apply(' is '.join, axis=1)`

You can shave off two more characters with `df.agg()`, but it's slower:

`df.astype(str).agg(' is '.join, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a specific case from my side with 10^11 rows in my dataframe, and in this case none of the proposed solution is appropriate. I have used categories, and this should work fine in all cases when the number of unique string is not too large. This is easily done in the R software with XxY with factors but I could not find any other way to do it in python (I'm new to python). If anyone knows a place where this is implemented I'd be glad to know.

```
def Create_Interaction_var(df,Varnames):
    '''
    :df data frame
    :list of 2 column names, say "X" and "Y". 
    The two columns should be strings or categories
    convert strings columns to categories
    Add a column with the "interaction of X and Y" : X x Y, with name 
    "Interaction-X_Y"
    '''
    df.loc[:, Varnames[0]] = df.loc[:, Varnames[0]].astype("category")
    df.loc[:, Varnames[1]] = df.loc[:, Varnames[1]].astype("category")
    CatVar = "Interaction-" + "-".join(Varnames)
    Var0Levels = pd.DataFrame(enumerate(df.loc[:,Varnames[0]].cat.categories)).rename(columns={0 : "code0",1 : "name0"})
    Var1Levels = pd.DataFrame(enumerate(df.loc[:,Varnames[1]].cat.categories)).rename(columns={0 : "code1",1 : "name1"})
    NbLevels=len(Var0Levels)

    names = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.product(dict(enumerate(df.loc[:,Varnames[0]].cat.categories)),
                                                dict(enumerate(df.loc[:,Varnames[1]].cat.categories)))),
                         columns=['code0', 'code1']).merge(Var0Levels,on="code0").merge(Var1Levels,on="code1")
    names=names.assign(Interaction=[str(x) + '_' + y for x, y in zip(names["name0"], names["name1"])])
    names["code01"]=names["code0"] + NbLevels*names["code1"]
    df.loc[:,CatVar]=df.loc[:,Varnames[0]].cat.codes+NbLevels*df.loc[:,Varnames[1]].cat.codes
    df.loc[:, CatVar]=  df[[CatVar]].replace(names.set_index("code01")[["Interaction"]].to_dict()['Interaction'])[CatVar]
    df.loc[:, CatVar] = df.loc[:, CatVar].astype("category")
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pandas import *
x = DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3]})
x

 x['bar'] = x.bar.astype("str") + " " + "is" + " " + x.foo
x.drop(['foo'], axis=1)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?