# split string column by "_", drop the preceding text, recombine str by "_" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, dataframe

```
>e = {0: pd.Series(['NHL_toronto_maple-leafs_Canada', 'NHL_boston_bruins_US', 'NHL_detroit_red-wings', 'NHL_montreal'])}

>df = pd.DataFrame(e)

>df

    0
0   NHL_toronto_maple-leafs_Canada
1   NHL_boston_bruins_US
2   NHL_detroit_red-wings
3   NHL_montreal
```

I want to:

1) split the above dataframe (Series) by '_'

2) drop the 'NHL' string

3) recombine the remaining text by '_'

4) attach the result in #3 to the original dataframe as the second column

To do this I tried the following:

```
>df2 = df.icol(0).str.split('_').apply(pd.Series).iloc[:,1:]

>df2

    1   2   3
0   toronto maple-leafs Canada
1   boston  bruins  US
2   detroit red-wings   NaN
3   montreal    NaN NaN
```

I tried to follow the suggestion in [combine columns in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/pandas-combine-string-and-int-columns) by doing something like:

```
>df2['4'] = df2.iloc[:,0] + "_" + df2.iloc[:,1] + "_" + df2.iloc[:,2]

>df2

    1   2   3   4
0   toronto maple-leafs Canada  toronto_maple-leafs_Canada
1   boston  bruins  US  boston_bruins_US
2   detroit red-wings   NaN NaN
3   montreal    NaN NaN NaN
```

However, you can see that in situations where a combine involves a cell that is NaN the end result is NaN as well. This is not what I want.

Column 4 should look like:

```
toronto_maple-leafs_Canada
boston_bruins_US
detroit_red-wings_US
montreal
```

Also is there an efficient way to do this type of operation as my real data set is quite large.

Comment: Do you mean something like `my_string.partition('_')[2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `apply` like this :

```
In [1782]: df[0].apply(lambda v: '_'.join(v.split('_')[1:]))
Out[1782]: 
0    toronto_maple-leafs_Canada
1              boston_bruins_US
2             detroit_red-wings
3                      montreal
Name: 0, dtype: object

In [1783]: df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda v: '_'.join(v.split('_')[1:]))
```

Surprisingly, applying `str` seem to be taking longer than `apply` :

```
In [1811]: %timeit df[0].apply(lambda v: '_'.join(v.split('_')[1:]))
10000 loops, best of 3: 127 µs per loop

In [1810]: %timeit df[0].str[4:]
1000 loops, best of 3: 179 µs per loop

In [1812]: %timeit df[0].str.split('_').str[1:].str.join('_')
1000 loops, best of 3: 553 µs per loop

In [1813]: %timeit df[0].str.split("_", 1).str[1]
1000 loops, best of 3: 374 µs per loop
```

Comment: `df[0].str[4:]` is fastest for rows > 1k. Depends on the size of data you tested. However, you could speed up your solution by using `lambda v: v.split('_', 1)[1]`

Comment: @fixxer & John Galt - thank you kindly to both of you for the detailed solutions. I will use cycle through them all and see which one is best for performance. The real data arrives on a daily basis and is only several hundred rows. The entire data set is in the millions but daily only a few hundred.

Comment: @JohnGalt - I also noticed that the lambda function is the fastest. Faster than df[0].str.split("_", 1).str[1]. The size of the data set is a few hundred rows.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to remove starting `'NHL_'` substring, you could just

```
In [84]: df[0].str[4:]
Out[84]:
0    toronto_maple-leafs_Canada
1              boston_bruins_US
2             detroit_red-wings
3                      montreal
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

However, if you *need* to split and join, you could use a `string method` like-

```
In [85]: df[0].str.split('_').str[1:].str.join('_')
Out[85]:
0    toronto_maple-leafs_Canada
1              boston_bruins_US
2             detroit_red-wings
3                      montreal
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Alternatively, you could also use `apply`

```
In [86]: df[0].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x.split('_')[1:])) # Also, x.split('_', 1)[1]
Out[86]:
0    toronto_maple-leafs_Canada
1              boston_bruins_US
2             detroit_red-wings
3                      montreal
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

And, as @DSM pointed out - *"`split` accepts an argument for the maximum number of splits"*

```
In [87]: df[0].str.split("_", 1).str[1]
Out[87]:
0    toronto_maple-leafs_Canada
1              boston_bruins_US
2             detroit_red-wings
3                      montreal
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Depending on the size of your data, you could benchmark these methods and use appropriate one.

Comment: `split` accepts an argument for the maximum number of splits, so `df[0].str.split("_", 1).str[1]` works too.  Although I agree that if we know that everything starts with `NHL_`, simply removing it is far and away the simplest.

Comment: Right. Didn't think about the arguments! Good catch. Thanks.