# Why does pandas series.map method work for column concatenation?

Tags: python, pandas

From a couple of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-panda-python) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/pandas-combine-string-and-int-columns), a simple way to concatenate columns in a dataframe is to use the map command, as in the example below.  The map function returns a series, so why can't just a regular series be used instead of map?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6]},index=['m','n','o'])
df['x'] = df.a.map(str) + "_x"

    a   b   x

m   1   4   1_x
n   2   5   2_x
o   3   6   3_x
```

This also works even though I'm specifically creating a series.

```
df['y'] = pd.Series(df.a.map(str)) + "_y"

    a   b   x    y
m   1   4   1_x  1_y
n   2   5   2_x  2_y
o   3   6   3_x  3_y
```

This doesn't work, it gives a TypeEror

```
df['z'] = df['a'] + "_z"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

This doesn't work either:

```
df['z'] = pd.Series(df['a']) + "_z"
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

I checked to see if map returns a different type of object under the hood, but it doesn't seem to:

```
type(pd.Series(df.a.map(str)))
pandas.core.series.Series

type(pd.Series(df['a']))
pandas.core.series.Series
```

I'm confused about what map is doing that makes this work and how whatever map does carries over into the subsequent string arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) maps the input values against a corresponding value in the passed in type.

Normally the passed in type is a series, dict or a function, in your case it's calling the str ctor as a function and just concatenating this with `'_x'`.

However, as you've found out `df['a'] + "_z"` and `pd.Series(df['a']) + "_z"` won't work as there is no operand defined for those types (`ndarray` with `str`).

You could do it using:

```
In [8]:    
df['a'].astype(str) + '_z'

Out[8]:
m    1_z
n    2_z
o    3_z
Name: a, dtype: object
```

The thing to consider is that when you call `df['a'].map(str)` the dtype is actually changed to `str`:

```
In [13]:    
df['a'].map(str).dtype
​
Out[13]:
dtype('O')
```

So you can see why your first version worked as you essentially changed the `dtype` or the series so the above is the same as `df['a'].astype(str)`