# How to concatenate multiple column values into a single column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question is same to [this posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/pandas-combine-string-and-int-columns) earlier. I want to concatenate three columns instead of concatenating two columns:

Here is the combining two columns:

```
df = DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3], 'new':['apple', 'banana', 'pear']})

df['combined']=df.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s' % (x['foo'],x['bar']),axis=1)

df
    bar foo new combined
0   1   a   apple   a_1
1   2   b   banana  b_2
2   3   c   pear    c_3
```

I want to combine three columns with this command but it is not working, any idea?

```
df['combined']=df.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s' % (x['bar'],x['foo'],x['new']),axis=1)
```

Comment: if you want to concat 3 columns you need 3 %s. (**%s_%s_%s**) like `df['combined']=df.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s_%s' % (x['bar'],x['foo'],x['new']),axis=1)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String concatenation of two pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns)

Comment: A more comprehensive answer showing timings for multiple approaches is [Combine two columns of text in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Your reference post later has `df.astype(str).agg('_'.join, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 184):

Another solution using `DataFrame.apply()`, with slightly less typing and more scalable when you want to join more columns:

```
cols = ['foo', 'bar', 'new']
df['combined'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: '_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

Comment: This is the best solution when the column list is saved as a variable and can hold a different amount of columns every time

Comment: Tiny gotcha I ran into was that `.values.astype(str)` converts `None` into the string `'None'` rather than an empty string. Apparently.

Comment: **without lambda** (faster and more concise): `df[cols].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)`. That said, using `.str.cat(...).str.cat(...)...` is faster still.

Answer (score 115):

You can use string concatenation to combine columns, with or without delimiters. You do have to convert the type on non-string columns.

```
In[17]: df['combined'] = df['bar'].astype(str) + '_' + df['foo'] + '_' + df['new']

In[17]:df
Out[18]: 
   bar foo     new    combined
0    1   a   apple   1_a_apple
1    2   b  banana  2_b_banana
2    3   c    pear    3_c_pear
```

Comment: this solution will be much faster compared to the `.apply(, axis=1)` one on bigger DFs

Comment: @MaxU yeah and its very easy.

Comment: I've added a [comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39293567/5741205) against 30K rows DF...

Comment: I'm getting a `SettingWithCopyWarning` when I use this solution - how could I avoid triggering that warning?

Comment: This gets annoying when you need to join many columns, however.

Comment: If any of the columns are `None`, `df['combined']` becomes `nan`. Example: if `df.new.iloc[0] == None`, then `df.combined.iloc[0]` becomes `nan`, instead of `1_a_`

Comment: what is I want to combine the columns based on a condition such as (if ```df['bar']==1```)?

Answer (score 29):

If you have even more columns you want to combine, using the Series method `str.cat` might be handy:

```
df["combined"] = df["foo"].str.cat(df[["bar", "new"]].astype(str), sep="_")
```

Basically, you select the first column (if it is not already of type `str`, you need to append `.astype(str)`), to which you append the other columns (separated by an optional separator character).

Comment: Clever, but this caused a huge memory error for me. Tedious as it may be, writing `df[col].map(str) + '_' df[col2].map(str) + ... + df[col9].map(str)` is way more efficient.

Comment: It's interesting! I didn't know we can use DataFrame as an argument in `Series.str.cat()`

Comment: This is by far the easiest for me, and I like the sep parameter

Comment: No memory issues for me. Has to add `df["foo"].fillna('')`.

Answer (score 18):

Just wanted to make a time comparison for both solutions (for 30K rows DF):

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3], 'new':['apple', 'banana', 'pear']})

In [2]: big = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [3]: big.shape
Out[3]: (30000, 3)

In [4]: %timeit big.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s_%s' % (x['bar'],x['foo'],x['new']),axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 881 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit big['bar'].astype(str)+'_'+big['foo']+'_'+big['new']
10 loops, best of 3: 44.2 ms per loop
```

a few more options:

```
In [6]: %timeit big.ix[:, :-1].astype(str).add('_').sum(axis=1).str.cat(big.new)
10 loops, best of 3: 72.2 ms per loop

In [11]: %timeit big.astype(str).add('_').sum(axis=1).str[:-1]
10 loops, best of 3: 82.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Very nice with additional options.

Answer (score 12):

Possibly the fastest solution is to operate in plain Python:

```
Series(
    map(
        '_'.join,
        df.values.tolist()
        # when non-string columns are present:
        # df.values.astype(str).tolist()
    ),
    index=df.index
)
```

Comparison against @MaxU answer (using the `big` data frame which has both numeric and string columns):

```
%timeit big['bar'].astype(str) + '_' + big['foo'] + '_' + big['new']
# 29.4 ms ± 1.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%timeit Series(map('_'.join, big.values.astype(str).tolist()), index=big.index)
# 27.4 ms ± 2.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comparison against @derchambers answer (using their `df` data frame where all columns are strings):

```
from functools import reduce

def reduce_join(df, columns):
    slist = [df[x] for x in columns]
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + '_' + y, slist[1:], slist[0])

def list_map(df, columns):
    return Series(
        map(
            '_'.join,
            df[columns].values.tolist()
        ),
        index=df.index
    )

%timeit df1 = reduce_join(df, list('1234'))
# 602 ms ± 39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit df2 = list_map(df, list('1234'))
# 351 ms ± 12.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer given by @allen is reasonably generic but can lack in performance for larger dataframes:

Reduce does **a lot** better:

```py
from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd

# make data
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1_000_000))
df['1'] = 'CO'
df['2'] = 'BOB'
df['3'] = '01'
df['4'] = 'BILL'


def reduce_join(df, columns):
    assert len(columns) > 1
    slist = [df[x].astype(str) for x in columns]
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x + '_' + y, slist[1:], slist[0])


def apply_join(df, columns):
    assert len(columns) > 1
    return df[columns].apply(lambda row:'_'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)

# ensure outputs are equal
df1 = reduce_join(df, list('1234'))
df2 = apply_join(df, list('1234'))
assert df1.equals(df2)

# profile
%timeit df1 = reduce_join(df, list('1234'))  # 733 ms
%timeit df2 = apply_join(df, list('1234'))   # 8.84 s
```

Comment: Is there a way to not abandon the empty cells, without adding a separator, for example, the strings to join is "", "a" and "b", the expected result is "_a_b", but is it possible to have "a_b". I couldn't find a way to do this efficiently, because it requires row wise operation, since the length of each row is different.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @Yang, maybe post a new question with a workable example?

Answer (score 8):

I think you are missing one *%s*

```
df['combined']=df.apply(lambda x:'%s_%s_%s' % (x['bar'],x['foo'],x['new']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 7):

First convert the columns to str. Then use the .T.agg('_'.join) function to concatenate them. More info can be gotten [here](https://datascientyst.com/combine-multiple-columns-into-single-one-in-pandas/)

```
# Initialize columns
cols_concat = ['first_name', 'second_name']

# Convert them to type str
df[cols_concat] = df[cols_concat].astype('str')

# Then concatenate them as follows
df['new_col'] = df[cols_concat].T.agg('_'.join)
```

Comment: Great comment. But did you have to use transpose at the end? Is it the same as .agg(''.join, axis=1)? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of columns you want to concatenate and maybe you'd like to use some separator, here's what you can do

```
def concat_columns(df, cols_to_concat, new_col_name, sep=" "):
    df[new_col_name] = df[cols_to_concat[0]]
    for col in cols_to_concat[1:]:
        df[new_col_name] = df[new_col_name].astype(str) + sep + df[col].astype(str)
```

This should be faster than `apply` and takes an arbitrary number of columns to concatenate.

Answer (score 2):

```
df = DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3], 'new':['apple', 'banana', 'pear']})

df['combined'] = df['foo'].astype(str)+'_'+df['bar'].astype(str)
```

If you concatenate with string('_') please you convert the column to string which you want and after you can concatenate the dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

```
df['New_column_name'] = df['Column1'].map(str) + 'X' + df['Steps']
```

X= x is any delimiter (eg: space) by which you want to separate two merged column.

Answer (score 2):

@derchambers I found one more solution:

```
import pandas as pd

# make data
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1_000_000))
df['1'] = 'CO'
df['2'] = 'BOB'
df['3'] = '01'
df['4'] = 'BILL'

def eval_join(df, columns):

    sum_elements = [f"df['{col}']" for col in columns]
    to_eval = "+ '_' + ".join(sum_elements)

    return eval(to_eval)


#profile
%timeit df3 = eval_join(df, list('1234')) # 504 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function which would make the implementation neater (esp. if you're using this functionality multiple times throughout an implementation):

```
def concat_cols(df, cols_to_concat, new_col_name, separator):  
    df[new_col_name] = ''
    for i, col in enumerate(cols_to_concat):
        df[new_col_name] += ('' if i == 0 else separator) + df[col].astype(str)
    return df
```

Sample usage:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
test = concat_cols(test, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'concat_col', '_')
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that one is combining three columns, one would need three format specifiers, `'%s_%s_%s'`, not just two `'%s_%s'`. The following will do the work

```
df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: '%s_%s_%s' % (x['foo'], x['bar'], x['new']), axis=1)

[Out]:
  foo  bar     new    combined
0   a    1   apple   a_1_apple
1   b    2  banana  b_2_banana
2   c    3    pear    c_3_pear
```

Alternatively, if one wants to create a separate list to store the columns that one wants to combine, the following will do the work.

```
columns = ['foo', 'bar', 'new']

df['combined'] = df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join([str(x[i]) for i in columns]), axis=1)

[Out]:
  foo  bar     new    combined
0   a    1   apple   a_1_apple
1   b    2  banana  b_2_banana
2   c    3    pear    c_3_pear
```

This last one is more convenient, as one can simply change or add the column names in the list - it will require less changes.

Answer (score 0):

*following to @Allen response*
If you need to chain such operation with other dataframe transformation, use `assign`:

```py
df.assign(
    combined = lambda x: x[cols].apply(
        lambda row: "_".join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1
  )
)
```