# Splitting a dataframe (csv)

Tags: python-3.x

How do i split a dataframe (csv) in the ratio of 4:1 randomly and store them in two different variables
*ex- if there are ten rows from 1 to 10 in the dataframe, i want any 8 rows from it in variable 'a' and the remaining 2 rows in variable 'b'.*

Comment: Typically, questions that are asked without code samples of what the asker has tried are closed as "off-topic" (and so don't get answered).. Next time, please include your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done this on a random basis but the basic approach would be:

1. import pandas  2)
2. read in your csv
3. drop empty/null columns(avoid issues with these)
4. create a new dataframe to put the split values into
5. assign names to your new columns
6. split values and combine the values (using apply/combine/lambda)

**Code sample:**

```
# importing pandas module 
import pandas as pd 

# read in csv file 
data = pd.read_csv("https://mydata.csv") 

# drop null values 
data.dropna(inplace = True) 

#  create new data frame 
new = data["ColumnName"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True) #this 'split' code applies to splitting one column into two

# assign new name to first column
data["A"]= new[0] #8 concatenated values will go here

# making seperate last name column from new data frame 
data["B"]= new[1]  #last two [combined] values in go here
```

## [other/different code required for concatenation of column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291499/how-to-concatenate-multiple-column-values-into-a-single-column-in-panda-datafram) - look at this linked SO question##

```
# df display 
data
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In machine learning, from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0), this is the code when a supervised leraning algorithm is used. What would be the code when it is unsupervised. Basically there is no 'y' in that case. Hope you get my question

Comment: @RahulRamaswamy I understand your question. I thought you may be able to adapt the code by integrating a) code from the linked question and b) your existing knowledge and logic. Was just trying to help!

Comment: To be honest i am unable to frame my exact problem here.