# How to concatenate values from multiple pandas columns on the same row into a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like that:

```
          true_time       amount     name      value  fruit
2019-11-28 12:57:00        0.59       AAA      81.98  apple
2019-11-28 12:58:00        2.37       BBB     261.98  orange
2019-11-28 12:59:00       559.4       CCC      71.45  banana
```

I'm trying to add an extra column to the end called `concat` which should contain a string of joined values from certain cells on the same row.

The result looks like this:

```
... fruit     concat
    apple     0.59-AAA-81.98
    orange    2.37-BBB-261.98
    banana    559.4-CCC-71.45
```

I tried bits and pieces but was not sure how to access multiple cells per row and ended up with this incomplete attempt.

```
df['concat'] = df['concat'].apply(lambda x: '{}-{}-{}'.format(loc[0], loc[1], loc[2]))
```

I might be needing a standalone function as I'm planning to hash the string and add the result to a `hash` column next to the `concat` column.

Comment: This is a duplicate. I apologise, I have missed this exact same question and the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291499/how-to-concatenate-multiple-column-values-into-a-single-column-in-panda-datafram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them like you would normally do with strings. Here's an easily reproducible example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Mark', 'Laura', 'Adam', 'Roger', 'Anna'],
                   'Car':['Audi', 'Tesla', 'BMW', 'Ford', 'Hyundai'],
                   'Money':[0, 50, 20, 15, 10]})

print(df)
```

```
Out[31]: 
    Name      Car  Money
0   Mark     Audi      0
1  Laura    Tesla     50
2   Adam      BMW     20
3  Roger     Ford     15
4   Anna  Hyundai     10
```

```
df['concat'] = df['Name'] + '-' + df['Money'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Car']
print(df)
```

```
Out[35]: 
    Name      Car  Money           concat
0   Mark     Audi      0      Mark-0-Audi
1  Laura    Tesla     50   Laura-50-Tesla
2   Adam      BMW     20      Adam-20-BMW
3  Roger     Ford     15    Roger-15-Ford
4   Anna  Hyundai     10  Anna-10-Hyundai
```

For numeric columns, don't forget to add `df['col'].astype(str)`

Comment: This is wrong, this would fail on numeric columns.

Comment: Read the last line, please.

Comment: Maybe make an example with numeric column as well?