# How to concatenate multiple columns in Excel using Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to concatenate multiple columns of Excel into single column using Python. Please find below the format:

[image]

and after concatenate it will make single column:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate multiple column values into a single column in Panda dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291499/how-to-concatenate-multiple-column-values-into-a-single-column-in-panda-datafram)

Comment: Thanks It's working. Actually I am importing the data from Excel. Still it's help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Load your ".csv" file to a DataFrame
- Get the column names
- Iterate through to concatenate the columns with `apply` function
- Store the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

output = pd.read_csv('../filename.csv')

cols = output.columns

df_new = output[cols].apply(lambda row: ' '.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)

df_new.to_csv('../filename_new.csv', sep='\t')
```

Comment: ID|NAME|FRIEND|UNFRIEND

Comment: there you go: `df_new = output[cols].apply(lambda row: '|'.join(row.values.astype(str)), axis=1)`

Comment: Yeah That's fine but I am not getting the header in my excel. Only values are coming             0            0|Will|33|385
1              1|Mark|26|2
2            2|Hugh|55|221                                                                                                   At 0 I was suppose to get column.