# How can I combine these columns in this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've tried combining it myself for a while and couldn't do it. I have a dataframe like this:

```
                           0                1             2       3       4       5      6       7
translatedText         Rsst,           11211,      Brooklyn     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText        Ttnft,       Taroudant,        111111     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText        Sstma,  St. Petersburg,        B-8601     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText     Gzprmbnk,     Ekaterinburg        HUJ852     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText        Nrilsk           Nckel,          Edsn   85748     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText       Phsgro,           smrvll             -  134567     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText            TO             mtrs           rs,     Mnl    Prkn       /  F68E1     NaN
translatedText      Arktkgz,         metuchen             -   B1234     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText  Srgtnftegas,             srdn             -  HUJ852     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText           Sct             Ntnl  d'invstssmnt  London  AB9014     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText       MrsMrc,        new York,        IHBCSD     NaN     NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN
translatedText          Albb              Grp         Hldng    Ltd.       -  Boston      ;  805BDS
translatedText        Tehran                /      Montreal       -   69801     NaN    NaN     NaN
```

I want it to look like this

```
                 translatedText
0  Rsst, 11211, Brooklyn
1  Ttnft, Taroudant, 111111
2  Sstma, St. Petersburg, B-8601
3  Gzprmbnk, Ekaterinburg HUJ852
4  Nrilsk Nckel, Edsn 85748
5  TO mtrs rs, Mnl Prkn / F68E1
6  Arktkgz, metuchen - B1234
7  Srgtnftegas, srdn -  HUJ852
8  Sct Ntnl d'invstssmnt London AB9014
9  MrsMrc, new York, IHBCSD
10 Albb Grp Hldng Ltd. - Boston; 805BDS
11 Tehran / Montreal - 69801
```

Not really sure what to do here. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate multiple column values into a single column in Panda dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291499/how-to-concatenate-multiple-column-values-into-a-single-column-in-panda-datafram)

Comment: Have a look here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098383/merge-multiple-column-values-into-one-column-in-python-pandas

Answer (score 0):

you can use `join` fuction for it

```
df['merged'] = df[df.columns[0:]].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),
    axis=1)
```