# Combine Value in Multiple Columns (With NA condition) Into New Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data:

```
ID  merk_ac1  merk_ac2 merk_ac3
1   a         NA       NA
2   NA        b        NA
3   NA        a        b
4   a,b       NA       c
```

I tried using `combine_first()` but not cover the multiple values. I want the result like:

```
ID  merk_ac1  merk_ac2 merk_ac3 merk_ac
1   a         a                 a 
2             b                 b
3             a        b        a,b
4   a,b                c        a,b,c
```

Comment: Is this a [tag:pandas] dataframe? If so, please add the tag to your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate multiple column values into a single column in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291499/how-to-concatenate-multiple-column-values-into-a-single-column-in-pandas-datafra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply to concatenate string from multiple columns using `join`.
For unique/distinct value/element you can transform list into `set` and then `join` it **set will not respect sorting order** if you want in sorted you can just do `sorted(list(set()))`.

```py
import pandas as pd

a = ["a", pd.NA, pd.NA, "a,b"]
b = ["a", "b", "a", pd.NA]
c = [pd.NA, pd.NA, "b", "c"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"merk_ac1": a, "merk_ac2": b, "merk_ac3": c})
df["combined"]=df.apply(lambda row: ",".join(set([elem for elem in row if not pd.isna(elem)])), axis=1)
df.head()
```

OUTPUT:

|  | a | b | c | combined |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | a | NA | a |
| 1 | NA | b | NA | b |
| 2 | NA | a | b | a,b |
| 3 | a,b | NA | c | c,a,b |

Comment: thank you. but if I want a distinct value in every row it is possible? for example the values of merk_ac1 and merk_ac2 are a. using your code the result will be a,a. I want only a.

Comment: Check I have updated my answer. If this solves your doubt you can mark it as **Answer** and avoid updating question with new condition if your doubt is solved and try to ask question with proper condition at first.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
import numpy as np
import panas as pd

df['merk_ac'] = df.apply(lambda x: [element for element in x if ~np.isnan(element)],axis = 1)
```

assuming that in `merk_ac` you want a list with all the elements from the different columns of the original data frame

Comment: Did you check whether `~np.isnan(element)` is working in this string case?