# How to convert dataframe columns into key:value strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am preparing dataset for openai model training. For an example, I have data in csv in below format

```
df = DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3], 'new':['apple', 'banana', 'pear']})

df
    bar foo new 
0   1   a   apple   
1   2   b   banana  
2   3   c   pear
```

I want to create a new column called 'prompt' with combine values of bar and foo columns

```
    bar foo new     prompt  
0   1   a   apple   foo: a, bar: 1
1   2   b   banana  foo: b, bar: 2
2   3   c   pear    foo:c, bar: 3
```

there is similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291499/how-to-concatenate-multiple-column-values-into-a-single-column-in-pandas-datafra) but it doesn't add the column names inside the combined column

Comment: You want to make an object from the columns? {col1: value1, col2: value2, col3: value3}?

Comment: @dasfacc not exactly a object but string in the same format with curly brackets. `{col1: value1, col2: value2, col3: value3}`

Comment: @g1soori Your comment has curly braces but your question text doesn't. Which one did you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`df.apply` is very popular but [should be avoided whenever possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/13138364).

Instead use vectorized methods. Convert the relevant columns to dict and remove the quotes:

```
df["prompt"] = df[["foo", "bar"]].to_dict(orient="index")
df["prompt"] = df["prompt"].astype(str).replace(r"'", "", regex=True)

#   foo  bar     new            prompt
# 0   a    1   apple  {foo: a, bar: 1}
# 1   b    2  banana  {foo: b, bar: 2}
# 2   c    3    pear  {foo: c, bar: 3}
```

Note that [your comment included braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75152349/how-to-convert-dataframe-columns-into-keyvalue-strings/75152902#comment132619758_75152349) but your post did not. If you also want to remove the curly braces, add them to the regex:

```
df["prompt"] = df["prompt"].astype(str).replace(r"[{'}]", "", regex=True)

#   foo  bar     new          prompt
# 0   a    1   apple  foo: a, bar: 1
# 1   b    2  banana  foo: b, bar: 2
# 2   c    3    pear  foo: c, bar: 3
```

---

#### Details

First convert the relevant columns [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) oriented by index:

```
df["prompt"] = df[["foo", "bar"]].to_dict(orient="index")

#   foo  bar     new                  prompt
# 0   a    1   apple  {'foo': 'a', 'bar': 1}
# 1   b    2  banana  {'foo': 'b', 'bar': 2}
# 2   c    3    pear  {'foo': 'c', 'bar': 3}
```

Then use [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to convert it to `str` type and [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) the dict symbols:

```
df["prompt"] = df["prompt"].astype(str).replace(r"[{'}]", "", regex=True)

#   foo  bar     new          prompt
# 0   a    1   apple  foo: a, bar: 1
# 1   b    2  banana  foo: b, bar: 2
# 2   c    3    pear  foo: c, bar: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':['a','b','c'], 'bar':[1, 2, 3], 'new':['apple', 'banana', 'pear']})
df['prompt'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.to_json(), axis=1)
df
```

This would work? You get:

```
    foo bar new     prompt
0   a   1   apple   {"foo":"a","bar":1,"new":"apple"}
1   b   2   banana  {"foo":"b","bar":2,"new":"banana"}
2   c   3   pear    {"foo":"c","bar":3,"new":"pear"}
```

Comment: Its short and sweet and works for my example. but I prefer the solution from tdy as it can filter out the required columns instead of combining all the columns. thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Combine multiple cells in a row using [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and `lambda`

```
df['prompt']=df.apply(lambda k: 'foo: ' + k['foo'] + ', bar: ' + str(k['bar']), axis=1)
```

This will work?

```
  foo  bar     new          prompt
0   a    1   apple  foo: a, bar: 1
1   b    2  banana  foo: b, bar: 2
2   c    3    pear  foo: c, bar: 3
```

Comment: My actual csv file has 50 columns so I don't want to specify each column in the lambda. thanks for the response