# How do I merge multiple columns into 1 column in a Pandas dataframe? I have lots of cells with empty values and wish to shift to all be in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How would I clean up my data so that empty cells are removed? I've shown an example of my problem in the table below. All of my data to be merged is ***textual*** but there are also numeric aspects as shown in the example. I have 17 columns in the dataframe.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10% | Data |  |
| 20% | Data |  |
| 30% |  | Data |

Desired:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 10% | Data |
| 20% | Data |
| 30% | Data |

I've tried to find a solution but failed. All the examples appear to be based on numerical data not written.

Comment: with `dropna()` to remove the blanks.

Comment: See this answer which gives several approaches [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39291499)

Answer (score 2):

i could answer this in a few ways, here is the first method using the `combine_first()` method:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the initial DataFrame with some missing values
data = {
    'Column A': ['10%', '20%', '30%'],
    'Column B': ['Data', 'Data', None],
    'Column C': [None, None, 'Data']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Move the data from Column C to Column B where Column B has missing values
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].combine_first(df['Column C'])

# Now you can drop Column C if it's no longer needed
df = df.drop(columns=['Column C'])

# Display the updated DataFrame
print(df)
```

returns this:

```
  Column A Column B
0      10%     Data
1      20%     Data
2      30%     Data
```

if the "data" is text, you cound also use concatenation:

```py
df['Column B'] = df['Column B'].fillna('') + df['Column C'].fillna('')
```

So long as the data is understood, there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic method, ensure the empty cells are NaN/None and [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html):

```
# select desired columns
cols = df.columns[1:]
# or manually:
# cols = ['Column B', 'Column C']

# ensure empty cells are None
# bfill and take the first column
df[cols[0]] = (df[cols].replace('', None)
               .bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
               )

# drop other columns
df.drop(columns=cols[1:], inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
  Column A Column B
0      10%     Data
1      20%     Data
2      30%     Data
```