# How to create strings from dataframe columns elements in Python?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe `df`, (real life is a +1000 row df). Elements of `ColB` are lists of lists.

```
  ColA    ColB
0  'A'    [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]
1  'B'    [['f','g','h'],['i','j','k']]
2  'A'    [['l','m','n'],['o','p','q']]
```

How can efficiently create a `ColC` that is a string using the elements in the different columns, like this:

```
      ColC
'A>+a b:c,+d e:f'
'B>+f g:h,+i j:k'
'A>+l m:n,+o p:q'
```

I tried with `df.apply` along these lines, [inspired by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/pandas-combine-string-and-int-columns):

```
df['ColC'] = df.apply(lambda x:'%s>' % (x['ColA']),axis=1)
```

This works for the first 2 elements of the string. Having a hard time with the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df['ColC']  = df.ColA + '>+' + df.ColB.str[0].str[0] + \
              ' ' + df.ColB.str[0].str[1] + ':' + \
              df.ColB.str[0].str[2] + ',+' + \
              df.ColB.str[1].str[0] + ' ' + \
              df.ColB.str[1].str[1] + ':' + \
              df.ColB.str[1].str[2]
```

Output:

```
  ColA                    ColB             ColC
0    A  [[a, b, c], [d, e, f]]  A>+a b:c,+d e:f
1    B  [[f, g, h], [i, j, k]]  B>+f g:h,+i j:k
2    A  [[l, m, n], [o, p, q]]  A>+l m:n,+o p:q
```

### Timings

df = pd.concat([df]*333)

Wen's Method

> %%timeit df[['t1','t2']]=df['ColB'].apply(pd.Series).applymap(lambda x
>   : ('{} {}:{}'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2]))) df.ColA+'>+'+df.t1+',+'+df.t2

*1 loop, best of 3: 363 ms per loop*

miradulo Method

> %%timeit df.apply(lambda r:'{}>+{} {}:{},+{}
>   {}:{}'.format(*flatten(r)), axis=1)

*10 loops, best of 3: 74.9 ms per loop*

ScottBoston Method

> %%timeit df.ColA + '>+' + df.ColB.str[0].str[0] + \
>                 ' ' + df.ColB.str[0].str[1] + ':' + \
>                 df.ColB.str[0].str[2] + ',+' + \
>                 df.ColB.str[1].str[0] + ' ' + \
>                 df.ColB.str[1].str[1] + ':' + \
>                 df.ColB.str[1].str[2]

*100 loops, best of 3: 12.4 ms per loop*

Comment: @Wen LOL... Okay after tonight.  Must support Astros today!

Comment: @miradulo Oh... i mulipled the size of the original data by 333 to simulate 1000 rows.

Comment: @ScottBoston Ah, fair enough - I guess the brute string representation approaches dominates for performance once the rows get big enough, +1

Comment: @ScottBoston Yes, but as far as i can tell it's the only way to generalize... sigh.

Answer (score 2):

You are right using `apply`

```
df[['t1','t2']]=df['colB'].apply(pd.Series).applymap(lambda x : ('{} {}:{}'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2])))
df.colA+'>+'+df.t1+',+'+df.t2
Out[648]: 
0    A>+a b:c,+d e:f
1    B>+f g:h,+i j:k
2    C>+l m:n,+o p:q
```

Comment: @hernanavella I create two new columns for restore the temporary value :-), then we can use simple add to create the string you want

Answer (score 2):

If we make use of a `flatten` function as follows

```
def flatten(l):
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            yield from flatten(el)
        else:
            yield el
```

as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/4686625), then we can easily `apply` a string formatting with the flattened elements.

```
>>> df.apply(lambda r:'{}>+{} {}:{},+{} {}:{}'.format(*flatten(r.values)), axis=1)
0    A>+a b:c,+d e:f
1    B>+f g:h,+i j:k
2    A>+l m:n,+o p:q
dtype: object
```

This would hopefully generalize somewhat well.

```
>>> row_formatter = lambda r: '{}>+{} {}:{},+{} {}:{}'.format(*flatten(r.values))
>>> df.apply(row_formatter, 1)
0    A>+a b:c,+d e:f
1    B>+f g:h,+i j:k
2    A>+l m:n,+o p:q
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another answer:

```
df['ColC'] = df.apply(lambda x: '%s>+%s %s:%s,+%s%s:%s'% tuple([x['ColA']]+x['ColB'][0]+x['ColB'][1]),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my 2 cents also using `apply`

Define a function that you can apply to the dataframe and use string formatting to parse your columns

```
def get_string(x):
    col_a = x.ColA
    col_b = (ch for ch in x.ColB if ch.isalnum())
    string = '{0}>+{1} {2}:{3},+{4} {5}:{6}'.format(col_a.strip("\'"), *col_b)
    return(string)

df['ColC'] = df.apply(get_string, axis=1)
df.ColC

0    A>+a b:c,+d e:f
1    B>+f g:h,+i j:k
2    A>+l m:n,+o p:q
```

I like this because it's easy to modify the format, though using apply in this way might be slow