# Pandas assign with str columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, assign

I really love the `pandas.assign()` function, especially in combination with the `lambda` expression.
However, I ran into an unknown behavior when dealing with string concatenation that I don't understand yet. I have found this thread, but it does not answer my question:
[String concatenation of two pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns)

Minimal working example of my problem:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Firstname': ['Sandy', 'Peter', 'Dolly'],
                   'Surname': ['Sunshine', 'Parker', 'Dumb']})
```

which returns

```py
  Firstname   Surname
0     Sandy  Sunshine
1     Peter    Parker
2     Dolly      Dumb
```

Now, if I'd like to assign e.g. `Full Name` I thought I could simply do:

```py
df = df.assign(**{'Full Name': lambda x: f'{x.Firstname} {x.Surname}'})
```

but this does not just create a new string like "Sandy Sunshine" based on **each** row (as expected) but on **all** rows like this:

[image: weird_pandas_assign_behavior]

Could anyone explain me why my approach does not work and why this

```py
df = df.assign(**{'Full Name': lambda x: x.Firstname + ' ' + x.Surname})
```

obviously works? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

```
df.assign(**{'Full Name': lambda x: f'{x.Firstname} {x.Surname}'})
```

That's where you are doing wrong.

`f-strings` keep whatever that is processed in the `{}` to the string.
Example:

```
print(f"Hello {df} world")
hello  0    Sandy
1    Peter
2    Dolly
Name: Firstname, dtype: object world
```

So, the output of `f'{x.Firstname} {x.Surname}'` would be

```
0    Sandy
1    Peter
2    Dolly
Name: Firstname, dtype: object 0    Sunshine
1      Parker
2        Dumb
Name: Surname, dtype: object
```

Now `df.assign(new_col = 'a')` would output:

```
 Firstname   Surname new_col
0     Sandy  Sunshine       a
1     Peter    Parker       a
2     Dolly      Dumb       a
```

That's the reason why you got the below string in every row.

```
0    Sandy
1    Peter
2    Dolly
Name: Firstname, dtype: object 0    Sunshine
1      Parker
2        Dumb
Name: Surname, dtype: object
```

In second case:

```
df.assign(**{'Full Name': lambda x: x.Firstname + ' ' + x.Surname})
```

Equivalent to

```
df.assign(Full_name = df['Firstname'] + ' ' + df['Surname']
```

It' just string concatenation element-wise so it worked as intended.

You can use `pd.Series.str.cat` here.

```
df['Full Name'] = df['Firstname'].str.cat(df['Surname'],sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of

```
f'{df.Firstname} {df.Surname}'
```

has type `str` and is the string representation of a pandas series while the type of

```
df.Firstname + ' ' + df.Surname
```

is `pandas.core.series.Series`. Because of this the assigment is treated differently.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas `f-string`s working elementwise for combine strings, because not exist solution implemented for arrays.

So in your solution are combine all `Series` (columns in df).

If need use `f-string`s one possible solution is loop in zipped columns pro processing each pair separately:

```
df = df.assign(**{'Full Name': lambda x: [f'{Firstname} {Surname}' 
                                         for Firstname, Surname in 
                                         zip(x['Firstname'], x['Surname'])]})
print (df)
  Firstname   Surname       Full Name
0     Sandy  Sunshine  Sandy Sunshine
1     Peter    Parker    Peter Parker
2     Dolly      Dumb      Dolly Dumb
```