# Create a new dataframe based on two columns of value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1` in python as below:

```
Type Category
a      1
b      2
c      3
d      4
```

Expected output:

```
Type
a/1 
b/2
c/3
d/4
```

The actual dataframe is way larger than this thus i can't type out every cells for the new dataframe.

How can I extract the columns and output to another dataframe with the '/' seperated? Maybe using some for loop?

Comment: Try: `df['Type']+'/'+df['Category'].astype(str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using `str.cat`

The right pandas-y way to proceed is by using `str.cat`

```py
df['Type'] = df.Type.str.cat(others=df.Category.astype(str), sep='/')
```

`others` contains the `pd.Series` to concatenate, and `sep` the separator to use.

Result

```
    Type
0   a/1
1   b/2
2   c/3
3   d/4
```

### Performance comparison

```py
%%timeit
df.Type.str.cat(others=df.Category.astype(str), sep='/')
>> 286 µs ± 449 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```py
%%timeit
df['Type'] + '/' + df['Category'].astype(str)
>> 348 µs ± 5.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Both solutions give the same result, but using `str.cat` is about ~20% faster.

Comment: Oh what if i need to add something before?

Something like C:/a/1


How can i add the C:/ before it?

Comment: In this case, you might want to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11858532/13765085
If you just want a simple way, just go with the first comment left on your question