# CONCAT and DELETE nan in each row and have the result in a other Column

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

i just learn the basic in Panda and im looking a way to concat and delete nan value and get the result in a new column of my dataframe.

I know how to concat, how to create list but not realy how to iterate trought the column delete the nan value and finally concat the result in the new column.

i have a table with different number and i would like to create a column with panda (CONTACT[CALLER_PHONE] = ...) with all the number from each row and no null values.
Exemple of result that i want in a table:

```
Number1     Number2      Number3      CALLER_PHONE
0675416952  0675416941   0675416930   0675416952,067541694,0675416930
Nan         0675417080   0675417082   0675417080,0675417082
Nan         Nan          0675837759   0675837759
```

My Code :

```
import pandas as pd

CONTACT = pd.read_excel('O:/16_GIS_Team/X_Tools/Model Builder And Parcels Package/Contact_20200807/CONTACT_20200807.xlsx')

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

CONTACT['CALLER_NAME'] = CONTACT['First Name'].str.cat(CONTACT['Last Name'], sep =" ")

cols = CONTACT[['Work Phone','Mobile','Home Phone','SMS marketing phone','Other Phone Number','Details (USA): Caller Phone']]

print(cols)

columns = list(cols)

for i in columns:
    Clean_Columns = cols.dropna(axis=1, how='any')
    print (Clean_Columns[i][2])
```

My files is an Excel
CONTACT is my dataframe

I try to iterate trought the column, than use dropna and get a cain of result with the list but its not working and i didn't dig deeper.

[Error with my list peace of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTTU0.png)

Im open to any advise thank you very much by advance!

Comment: Hello, please add your code as text, instead of images and make sure that you provide a minimal, reproducible example, so that others can help you (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Skalpa, Welcome to SO. To ensure your question is answered as soon as possible, take some time to read and understand [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking good questions. The best questions include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ok i will edit my post to be more easier to read

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation of two pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns)

Comment: @pnovotnyq my problem is i want to concat but without the nan values, i dont how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own function that will take the numbers you select and return as a string where the numbers are delimited with ','.

```
# get the data
cols = CONTACT[['Work Phone','Mobile','Home Phone','SMS marketing phone','Other Phone Number','Details (USA): Caller Phone']]

def concatenate_numbers(s):
    """Remove all NA values from a series and return as a string joined by ','"""
    s = s.dropna()
    return ','.join([str(number) for number in s])

# create a new column by applying the above function to every row of the dataframe.
df['all_phones'] = df.apply(concatenate_numbers, axis=1)
```

[pandas.Series.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) returns a pandas.Series with dropped NA values, so you need to assign that to a variable. You can then create a new column in the dataframe from the result.

Comment: Hy, thank you for you answer, sorry if my question is not clear enought, i put an exemple in the question right now, may be you will understand better.

I don<t want to delete the all row just the value and than concat the all row.

Comment: You may want to look into [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns).

Comment: It may help but how can i do to don t concat the NaN value ?

Comment: my problem is i want to concat but without the nan values, i dont how to do it

Comment: Your problem might be that your "NaN values" are not actual missing values, but rather the strings "Nan". This code only gets rid of actual missing values.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to create a list for your columns. Just use df["column_name"].columns

df = df.dropna()
or
df = df[df["columns_name"] != np.nan]

Comment: `dropna()` is the correct answer. np.nan doesn't equal anything, not even np.nan. In other words, `np.nan == np.nan` evaluates to False. To test for NaN values, you can use `pd.isnull()`.

Comment: the think is with dropna you delete all the row no ?

Comment: Yes, where `dropna()` decides to drop, it will drop the whole row (or column).

Comment: the think is i want to keep the row because there is other value that i want to keep and after concat in the new column (you can look the table example that i put)