# writing expression in python: multiply string to int

Tags: python, pandas, sympy

I have two DataFrames: one has string and the other has int. I am trying to multiply these two to generate  an algebraic expression:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
df2=pd.DataFrame(["x","y","z"])
```

**Expected Output:** [image]

How to generate the expression with two different data types?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation of two pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns)

Comment: I Tried this:`df1[0]+"is"+df2[0].map(str)` but got error.

Comment: Do you want an actual algebraic expression as in sympy or are `df1` just the coefficients for `df2` and you want to print the formula?

Comment: Edited the expected output. These are not coefficients but multiplying factors.

Comment: Why are using dataframe for this? You can do this by `string concatenation` without using pandas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
formula = ""    

# looping through tuples of (x, 1) (y, 2) (z, 3)

for val, var in zip(df1.values,df2.values):

    # formatting the value and variable in the current tuple 
    # and appending to the initially empty formula string

    formula += "{}*{}+".format(val[0], var[0])
```

## dirty quick way to remove last + sign

formula = formula[:-1]

Comment: I am still getting '00+' in output

Comment: You're looping on column names, not values!

Comment: Almost close, it adds addition + sign at the last: '1*x+2*y+3*z+'. Pls also add some comments so that it becomes easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import pandas as pd 

df1=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
df2=pd.DataFrame(["x","y","z"])
   
formula = '+'.join([f'{var[0]}*{val[0]}' for val, var in zip(df1.values,df2.values)])
     
print(formula)
```

Comment: multiplication sign * is missing