# How to merge cells into one with pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have a dataframe

| name | phone | address | neighborhood |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client1 | xxxxx | AStreet | Brooklyn ------ |
| client2 | xxxxx | BStreet | Brooklyn ------ |

etc...

I need to "combine" the cells in each row to be a single cell with all the info, occupying 4 columns. It should look like this:

| name | phone | address | neighborhood |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| client1, xxxxx, AStreet, Brooklyn -------- |  |  |  |
| client2, xxxxx, BStreet, Brooklyn -------- |  |  |  |

How to do this? Is this even posible? Sorry for the bad formatting, the guide wasn't very helpful on how to present a proper dataframe.

I've looked into many pandas methods for dataframes, but couldn't find an answer (perhaps i didn't notice it could be a solution, since i'm a beginner programmer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation of two pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns)

Comment: For example with `df.apply(', '.join, axis=1)`

Comment: That format is _okay_, someone can quickly get your data from it with `pd.read_clipboard`. The how-to-ask guide is site-wide, but there's a pretty detailed post about `pandas` specific tips for reproducible data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples with a few better ways

Comment: whoever edited my question has misrepresented it. I said I want all the info in one cell THAT TAKES UP 4 columns

Comment: @VniVersvs that's not possible. There's no such thing as a "merged cell" in pandas (in the way that there is in excel).

Comment: so i made a small picture with a "what i have" and then "what i want"

https://ibb.co/zfSZwPK

Comment: @ALollz i see. Perhaps some other library has it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit operation for this in pandas.

Yet, a straight forward solution would be something like this:

```py
df['name'] = df['name'] + ', ' + df['phone'] + ', ' + df['address'] + ', ' + df['phone']
df['phone'] = df['address'] = df['neighborhood'] = ''
```

You can always improve this (e.g. use `join` clause in the assignment):

```py
df['name'] = df.apply(', '.join, axis=1)
df['phone'] = df['address'] = df['neighborhood'] = ''
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but whoever edited my question misrepresented it, and i have no idea how to revert to the original editing. The question as it stands above is not what I need answered.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this is what you want:

```
out = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns)

df.iloc[:,:-1] += ', '
out["name"] = df.sum(1)
```

**Output**

```
                                       name phone address neighborhood
0  client1, xxxxx, AStreet, Brooklyn ------   NaN     NaN          NaN
1  client2, xxxxx, BStreet, Brooklyn ------   NaN     NaN          NaN
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but whoever edited my question misrepresented it, and i have no idea how to revert to the original editing. The question as it stands above is not what I need answered.