# Pandas dataframe, checking if row has exceptions and creating multiple string variables depending if row shows up multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm stuck on figuring this out. I have the following df I created from output. I'm looping through to get the `table_name`, `schema`, `column_name` and `comment`. I want to make sure there is a comment present, and if there is create a string query that appends to the list `query_list`.

```
output =  [['table_name', 'schema_name', 'column_name', 'data_type', 'null?', 'default', 'kind', 'expression', 'comment', 'database_name', 'autoincrement'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SFO', '_LOAD_DATETIME', '{"type":"TIMESTAMP_LTZ","precision":0,"scale":9,"nullable":true}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', 'DATE of Account', 'VE'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SFO', '_LOAD_FILENAME', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', 'file name', 'VE'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SFO', '_LOAD_FILE_TIMESTAMP', '{"type":"TIMESTAMP_NTZ","precision":0,"scale":9,"nullable":true}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'VE'], ['CUSTOMER', 'SFO', 'SUBSCRIPTIONSLIST', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'VE'], ['CUSTOMER', 'SFO', 'CONTACTROLESLIST', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', 'list of contract', 'VE'], ['DATA', 'SFO', 'OPPORTUNITY_NAME', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'VE']]

output = filter(bool, output)
df = pd.DataFrame(output)


df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]

query_list = []
grouped_comments = ''

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['comment'] is not None and row['comment'] != '':
        
        if len(row['table_name']) > 1:
            # the below doesn't work, it groups all table comments together

            sql = f"(COLUMN {row['column_name']} COMMENT '{row['comment']}')"
            grouped_comments = grouped_comments + sql

        elif len(row['table_name']) == 1:
            sql = f"ALTER TABLE {row['schema_name']}.{row['table_name']} ALTER COLUMN {row['column_name']} COMMENT '{row['comment']}';"

        query_list.append(sql)
```

Now the part I'm stuck on getting, is if there is a comment present and if the `table_name` shows up **more then once** then it should create a string that looks like the below, so it should be fetching all the `column_name` and `comment` and grouping into one string for that `table_name`:

```
"ALTER TABLE VE.ACCOUNT ALTER (COLUMN _LOAD_DATETIME COMMENT 'DATE of Account', COLUMN _LOAD_FILENAME COMMENT 'file name');"
```

and the elif works because if table_name only shows up once then it populates the correct string:

```
"ALTER TABLE VE.CUSTOMER ALTER COLUMN CONTACTROLESLIST COMMENT 'list of contract';"
```

so finally if I have the 2 above strings then my query_list should look like:

```
query_list = ["ALTER TABLE VE.ACCOUNT ALTER (COLUMN _LOAD_DATETIME COMMENT 'DATE of Account', COLUMN _LOAD_FILENAME COMMENT 'file name');",
 "ALTER TABLE VE.CUSTOMER ALTER COLUMN CONTACTROLESLIST COMMENT 'list of contract';"]
```

Comment: Could you match your sample data, current result, and expected output?  There is no `w` or `'x'` in your sample data. It is easier to follow if those are matching. You can modify either the sample data or result, whichever it is easy for you.

Comment: Do you need alter statement only where it has a comment?  Do you discard any rows with no comments?

Comment: @Emma yes only when there is a comment present, otherwise the other rows are unused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can filter out unnecessary rows.

```py
df = df[df.comment.notnull() & (df.comment.str.len() > 0)]
```

Then, concatenate the column statement.

```py
df['column_prop'] = 'COLUMN ' + df.column_name + ' COMMENT \'' + df.comment + '\''
```

Now, aggregate the `column_prop` to join the string, group by the table name.

```py
df = df.groupby(['database_name', 'table_name']).agg({'column_prop': lambda x: ', '.join(x)}).reset_index()
```

This will give you the following.

```
0 database_name table_name                                                                                 column_prop
0            VE    ACCOUNT  COLUMN _LOAD_DATETIME COMMENT 'DATE of Account', COLUMN _LOAD_FILENAME COMMENT 'file name'
1            VE   CUSTOMER                                          COLUMN CONTACTROLESLIST COMMENT 'list of contract'
```

From here, you can concatenate the each columns with additional string to obtain your desired string.

If your dataframe is small, you can simply concatenate like this.

```py
df['sql'] = 'ALTER TABLE ' + df.database_name + '.' + ...
```

Or check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298586/2956135 for better string concatenation approach.

Comment: thank you this is great! I wanted this to be in a list though because I'm using the snowflakehook and it requires a list https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/snowflake/hooks/snowflake.py#L269

Comment: You can do `df.sql.values.tolist()` at the end once you have generated the whole statement in `sql` column

Comment: thank you! I got too caught up with looping, but pandas has a lot to offer without having to do that. thanks!