# How to concatenate series in Python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I've the following code:

```
def excel_date(date1):
    temp = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    delta = date1 - temp  if date1 != 0 else temp - temp
    return float(delta.days) + (float(delta.seconds) / 86400)

df3['SuperID'] = df3['Break_date'].apply(excel_date)
df3['SuperID2'] = df3['ticker'] + str(df3['SuperID'])
```

Where I use a date to insert in date1 and I get a number from the excel date function.

My ticker and SuperID fields are OK:

[image: df3 print]

I want to concatenate both **and get TSLA44462** BUT it's concatenating the whole series if I use `str()` or `.astype(str)` in my SuperID column.

The column types:

[image: print dtypes]

Comment: Please add details of the `df3` dictionary in your question. As it currently is, it is very difficult to understand what this `df3` looks like, and how is it being populated; and is it even necessary.

Comment: Does this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns

Answer (score 1):

Here my solution if I understood your problem :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.4], "Col2":["Michel", "Sardou", "Paul", "Jean"], "Other Col":[2,3,5,2]})
df["Concat column"] = df["Col1"].astype(int).astype(str) + df["Col2"]
df[df["Concat column"] == "1Michel"]
```

or

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.4], "Col2":["Michel", "Sardou", "Paul", "Jean"], "Other Col":[2,3,5,2]})
df[(df["Col1"]==1) & (df["Col2"]=="Michel")]
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours of investigation and the help of comments the way to work with series, integers, floats and strings which worked for me is this:

```
    def excel_date(date1):
        temp = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
        delta = date1 - temp  if date1 != 0 else temp - temp
        return float(delta.days) + (float(delta.seconds) / 86400)
```

First of all I convert float to integer to avoid decimals.  int(x) is not feasible for series, so you better use .astype(int) which works fine.

```
    df3['SuperID'] = df3['Break_date'].apply(excel_date).astype(int)
```

After that, convert everything to char with char.array and not str(x) or .astype.   You then just need to sum columns using .astype(str) to get the desired result.

```
    a = np.char.array(df3['ticker'].values)
    b = np.char.array(df3['SuperID'].values)
    df3['SuperID2'] = (a + b).astype(str)
```

Hope this help to others working with series.

regards