# Creating Message column from dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

a little help here. So I am trying to create a msg column to utilise some information in the other columns. I have tried some few methods but I seem to be missing out on something. so this is a simulation

```
df
Name A B C
Jane 1 2 3
Celi 4 5 9

df[msg]=(f'''Hi {df.Name} you have {df.A} for A and {df.B} for B, making {df.C} in total for {(datetime.date.today()) - datetime.timedelta(days=7)} and {(datetime.date.today())}. ''')
```

expected output for first row

```
Hi Jane you have 1 for A and 2 for B, making 3 in total for 2022-09-25 to 2022-10-01

df
Name A B C msg
Jane 1 2 3  Hi Jane you have 1 for A and 2 for B, making 3 in total for 2022-09-25 to 2022-10-01
Celi 4 5 9  Hi Jane you have 1 for A and 2 for B, making 3 in total for 2022-09-25 to 2022-10-01
```

anything I could do to replicate for each row independently? As it produces all the names and info in one column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String concatenation of two pandas columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest moving your message-maker into its own function and applying this function to every row in your dataframe:

```py
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def make_message(row):
    datetime_today = datetime.date.today()
    return f'Hi {row.Name} you have {row.A} for A and {row.B} for B, making {row.C} in total for {datetime_today - datetime.timedelta(days=7)} and {datetime_today}.'

df = pd.DataFrame([['Jane', 1, 2, 3], ['Celi', 4, 5, 6]], columns=['Name', 'A', 'B', 'C'])
df['msg'] = df.apply(lambda row : make_message(row), axis=1)
```