# Combine two rows of date strings in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe that looks similar to the one below:

```
Date        A   B   C
01/01/2020  a1  b1  c1
03/17/2020  a2  b2  c2
03/30/2020  a3  b3  c3
06/24/2020  a4  b4  c4
06/25/2020  a5  b5  c5
11/01/2020  a6  b6  c6
11/20/2020  a7  b7  c7
05/17/2021  a8  b8  c8
05/18/2021  a9  b9  c9
08/13/2021  a10 b10 c10
08/16/2021  a11 b11 c11
09/27/2021  a12 b12 c12
09/27/2021  a13 b13 c13
12/07/2021  a14 b14 c14
12/07/2021  a15 b15 c15
02/25/2022  a16 b16 c16
```

What I am trying to do is make another column that we'll say would be called `daterange` where I am simply joining one row with the the next and sticking `' to '` in between, thus it should look like this:

```
Date        A   B   C   daterange
01/01/2020  a1  b1  c1  01/01/2020 to 03/17/2020
03/17/2020  a2  b2  c2  03/17/2020 to 03/30/2020
03/30/2020  a3  b3  c3  03/30/2020 to 06/24/2020
06/24/2020  a4  b4  c4  06/24/2020 to 06/25/2020
06/25/2020  a5  b5  c5  06/25/2020 to 11/01/2020
11/01/2020  a6  b6  c6  11/01/2020 to 11/20/2020
11/20/2020  a7  b7  c7  11/20/2020 to 05/17/2021
05/17/2021  a8  b8  c8  05/17/2021 to 05/18/2021
05/18/2021  a9  b9  c9  05/18/2021 to 08/13/2021
08/13/2021  a10 b10 c10 08/13/2021 to 08/16/2021
08/16/2021  a11 b11 c11 08/16/2021 to 09/27/2021
09/27/2021  a12 b12 c12 09/27/2021 to 09/27/2021
09/27/2021  a13 b13 c13 09/27/2021 to 12/07/2021
12/07/2021  a14 b14 c14 12/07/2021 to 12/07/2021
12/07/2021  a15 b15 c15 12/07/2021 to 02/25/2022
02/25/2022  a16 b16 c16
```

I have tried some functions such as `str.cat` but that unfortunately combines every row  when I am just looking to combine two rows together. Thinking that I could make use of `df['Date'] and df['Date'].shift()`?

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "Thinking that I could make use of `df['Date']` and `df['Date'].shift()`" ... [yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858472/string-concatenation-of-two-pandas-columns).

Answer (score 1):

```
df["end"] = df["Date"].shift(-1)
df["range"] = df['Date'].str.cat(df['end'], sep=' to ')
df.drop('end', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

````
          Date    A    B    C                     range
0   01/01/2020   a1   b1   c1  01/01/2020 to 03/17/2020
1   03/17/2020   a2   b2   c2  03/17/2020 to 03/30/2020
2   03/30/2020   a3   b3   c3  03/30/2020 to 06/24/2020
3   06/24/2020   a4   b4   c4  06/24/2020 to 06/25/2020
4   06/25/2020   a5   b5   c5  06/25/2020 to 11/01/2020
5   11/01/2020   a6   b6   c6  11/01/2020 to 11/20/2020
6   11/20/2020   a7   b7   c7  11/20/2020 to 05/17/2021
7   05/17/2021   a8   b8   c8  05/17/2021 to 05/18/2021
8   05/18/2021   a9   b9   c9  05/18/2021 to 08/13/2021
9   08/13/2021  a10  b10  c10  08/13/2021 to 08/16/2021
10  08/16/2021  a11  b11  c11  08/16/2021 to 09/27/2021
11  09/27/2021  a12  b12  c12  09/27/2021 to 09/27/2021
12  09/27/2021  a13  b13  c13  09/27/2021 to 12/07/2021
13  12/07/2021  a14  b14  c14  12/07/2021 to 12/07/2021
14  12/07/2021  a15  b15  c15  12/07/2021 to 02/25/2022
15  02/25/2022  a16  b16  c16  
​```
````

Comment: Thank you, this was close to what I was looking for! I was able to get something similar to that to work with just one line:
```df['daterange'] = df['Date'].str.cat(df['Date'].shift(-1), sep = ' to ')```

Answer (score 0):

`df['daterange'] = df['Date'].str.cat(df['Date'].shift(-1), sep = ' to ')`